conditional formating won't work but instead formats all cells
I'm using openpyxl
I just want to change the colour font of ALL CELLS IN A ROW IF the cell of a specific column is NOT None or !=. However, after several trials  modifying my code. The result formats all the cells instead.
col_check = sheet.max_row
red_font = Font(color='FF0000')
for row in range(row+1,col_check):
    if sheet.cell(row=row+1,column=col_check).value !='':
        for col in range(col_check+1):
           sheet.cell(row=row+1,column=col).font = red_font

Tried to make different variations of my code but I still kept having the same results.

Assigning a variable where that variable is required for the asignation for row in range(row+1,col_check) . An empty cell has the Python value of None, If you are testing for it the Pythonic way is if <cell value> is not None

I tried that too using:
      if sheet.cell(row=row+1,column=col_check).value is not None:

and still not result

For ws.iter_rows() by default the starting row will be the first row (1), the starting column is the first column (1). The ending row will be ws.max_row and the ending column will be ws.max_col. 
row[0].value is the value in the cell in Column A of the current row, 
row[1].value is the value in the cell in Column B of the current row... etc
With the following code;
For each row, if the cell in Column A has any value, all cells in that row will have the font changed to red.
If the cell in Column A is None the cells font will not be changed.
You can change if row[0].value is not None to refer to the 'specific column' you want to check is not None.
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Font


wb = load_workbook('foo.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']

for row in ws.iter_rows():
    cell_value = row[-1].value
    print(f"Cell Value is: '{cell_value}'")
    if cell_value is not None:
        for cell in row:
            cell.font = Font(color='FF0000')

wb.save('foo2.xlsx')


I tried that exact code. Replacing row[0] with the last column but it's still colouring the fonts of all cells

Then the cells are not None but rather must contain some value even if it is "" A blank value is not None. If you want either a blank value, i.e. len(row[0].value) = 0 or None then you can make those two the criteria.

You can add the print statement as shown. If it prints 'None' the cell value is None. If it prints anything else then cell value is not None.

Yeah I added the print statements and it does show None

I think I'll just try pandas instead. This is already getting too frustrated since I spent the whole day yesterday & today just for this. screw openpyxl

The program will only follow the logic, I can promise you that if your Cells are as described the font will be changed or not as required. It's a pretty basic operation. Do you have an IDE and tried debugging? I wouldn't have considered Pandas as a next choice for trying to change font colours, it's possible but the module is for manipulating the data not formatting styles.
